# Pure-FTPd user number X of Y?

Tags: ftp

When I connect to my private ftp account via filezilla :

What does it mean: "You are user number 7 of 100 allowed"

I hope I'm the only one who connects to this ftp account and that the last 6 connections are non-closed connections opened by myself !?

---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    220-You are user number 7 of 100 allowed.
    220-Local time is now 09:01. Server port: 21.
    220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
    220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: This doesn't look programming related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that 100 simultaneous connections are allowed to the FTP server.

You're user number 7 of 100.

The other 6 would be connected to different accounts.

Comment: ok, but I wonder that it's limited to only 100 connections, because it is a big web space provider and I would think that much more user  would like to be connected at the same time...